# How to access my LAMP virtual machine

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, lamp

I have an Ubuntu vm setup as a LAMP and I would like to access the localhost page of that machine and use that to test my websites. How can I access it?

Comment: please post your ip/networking setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Best network settings are:

   bridge-networking
   attached to your actual ethernet interfaces
2. in the vm verify your network settings

   ifconfig

if wrong, edit it here: `/etc/resolv.con` and `/etc/network/interfaces` and `/etc/host*`

1. use the ip to access the vm if the hostname does not resolv from your machine

Comment: :D let me guess: the default NAT or host-only settings did not work ;P

Answer (score 0):

You could also setup Virtual Hosts in your Virtual Machine:

```
 # edit the Apache config
 $ sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

# in apache2.conf, add these virtual host settings below the files node
 NameVirtualHost *:80

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot /var/www
   ServerName www.ubuntu.vm
   ServerAlias ubuntu.vm
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot /var/www/wordpress
   ServerName www.wordpress.vm
   ServerAlias wordpress.vm
</VirtualHost>
```

Much more info on how to setup a LAMP Development Environment in a Virtual Machine available in my blog post at: http://jimfrenette.com/2013/11/virtual-machine-for-lamp-development/